# How to extend HTMLElement with custom properties in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-component

I can't figure out how to properly extend a HTMLElement with custom attributes.

Need to create a npm package for a webcomponent which includes only the types so that it can used with React, Vue or any other framework/library really. The webcomponent is not bundled as it is just included through a compiled js file.

Don't think I need to import react or react types, since it should be framework indepenent.

This is the custom web component:

```
<super-awesome source-id="foo" position="right" />
```

This is my current `index.d.ts` (not working):

```
type SuperAwesomePosition = "top" | "right" | "bottom" | "left"

interface SuperAwesome extends HTMLElement {
  "source-id": string
  position?: SuperAwesomePosition
}
declare namespace JSX {
  interface IntrinsicElements {
    ["super-awesome"]: SuperAwesome
  }
}
```

and here is the tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es6", "DOM"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "files": ["index.d.ts"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@foo/bar",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/foo/bar.git",
  "author": "xxx<xxx@xxx.io>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "types": "./index.d.ts"
}
```

and lastly the index.js file:

```
module.exports = {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `index.d.ts` should have been renamed as `types.d.ts` and placed in `src` folder. And `SuperAwesome` should extend `HTMLElement` partially like the followings.

```js
interface SuperAwesome extends Partial<HTMLElement> {
  "source-id": string
  position?: SuperAwesomePosition
}
```